# What is this weed and how do I kill it without killing the grass?

Tags: lawn, weed-control, weeds, herbicide

**What is this weed and how do I kill it without killing the grass?**

I've tried different brands of the usual spectrum herbicide that kills everything but doesn't kill grass, and everything - like clover, dandelions, etc - does die, but not this stuff. And I've tried the herbicide triclopyr, made for chickweed, etc., and I sprayed on a few times over a few weeks. The weed appears to die or die back, and then regrows. I've never seen it bloom, so I don't know if it is the wild violet that others talk about not being able to kill. Glyphosate will kill this, as I used that in areas that were solid weeds without grass; but Glyphosate also kills the grass, so I can't use it in the yard.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does look like wild violets, and they are difficult to eradicate, but triclopyr, or any other lawn weedkiller that purports to kill these, is much more effective used in autumn, see here https://www.thespruce.com/get-rid-of-wild-violets-in-the-lawn-2132476

Even so, you may need to be as persistent as the violets by carrying out repeat treatments.

Comment: Thanks, seems that way; I'll spray in the fall a few times. They are taking over my lawn; not that my lawn is perfect, and I don't want a perfect lawn, but it would be nice if it was mostly grass.

Comment: What is the exact name of the weed?

Comment: Viola odorata is the Latin/botanical name

Answer (score 1):

Should have you look at this site I am posting on Henbit to see if you think this is the same plant; look for opposite leaves, two leaves coming from the same joint on the stem...

How much of your lawn has this growing in it?  Lawn management practices are far superior to pesticides.  How low do you cut your grass, how do you water, fertilizers, aeration...we have a ton of stuff on cool season lawns right here on this site.  Check them out, please and send a picture of the entire lawn if you can.

[henbit](http://www.ediblewildfood.com/henbit.aspx)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15317)

Comment: Please put this in a comment, stormy. I can't transform it because I don't have enough rep points.

Comment: Bamboo's answer was chosen.  Why do I need to clarify at this moment?  You, Ms. Alina do not have enough rep points???  When to comment and when to answer...?  Grins.  It is tough making decisions but I can live with my mistakes!  I learn so much more this way...don't you?

Comment: Your answer was in the low quality queue. Because it was not a link only and because it was longer than one line, the only logical possibility was that it had been marked or flaged on purpose by a member, not by the site algorithms. After reading it, my impression was that indeed this does not answer the question and it may be a comment posted as an aswer by mistake. My first comment above is a standard formulation of the site, I didn't write it. That's why I added another comment to let you know what's happening. Please read carefully what I wrote.

Comment: What I wrote is that I don't have enough rep to transform it into a comment. I saw someone who can make it, don't remember who, maybe Niall C? I didn't say I don't have enough rep to comment or to answer myself. Please don't jump to conclusions.

Comment: Hi Alina! You might be able to edit that standard message. I'm not sure though, you'd have to check as soon as it gets posted to see if you have editing or deleting options, or ask a mod, since I don't really know how these things work. And yes, feel free to ask a moderator to convert something into a comment. Pinging Niall C in the chat room generally works best for that, since he usually responds quickly. If you feel like a post in that queue is offensive in any way, flag it for a moderator to look at right away! Thanks for your hard work!